# How to migrate Azure SQL databases via Azure DevOps steps without username and password(Azure Ad Based)?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I am trying to setup an azure sql server and database that will only allow AD-based access for
a) App Services and
b) Azure Devops pipeline migrations

I am assuming that this can be achieved by setting up an Azure SQL Server that is hooked up to the Azure AD and giving access to the Service Connection(AppReg) that I have setup in Azure DevOps.

How to run though let's say an executable like efbundle.exe(entity framework), passing to it a connection string that says to it to use Active Directory instead of username and password?

a) What is the setup needed on the Azure SQL server?

b) What is the setup in Azure Devops(apart from the service connection) to step which runs the database migration

c) What is the connection string looking like for this type of connectivity? I simply have:
 `Server=tcp:abcd.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=abcd-db;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;`

Comment: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/azure/2021/04/20/efcore-managed-identity.html

Comment: https://erikej.github.io/sqlserver/2021/01/11/azure-sql-advanced-deployment-part1.html

Comment: great blogs @erikEJ . Let me try to implement some things and see how it works.

Instead of the dacpac deploy, if someone wants to run an executable to deploy the migrations what are my options? https://erikej.github.io/sqlserver/2021/02/01/azure-sql-advanced-deployment-part4.html

Looking to use efbundle but I am not sure if it accepts any similar parameters like your dacpac step(SQL token)